# Eclipse cdt gdb: specify library to debug

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I'm using eclipse cdt mingw 7.3.0 windows 10 for debugging the dynamically loaded dll.

Problem is that program loads a lot of dlls and it takes minutes till gdb is connected to all of them, but I need only one.

Is there a possibility to specify in debug configuration the library that I want to debug and load only this one in gdb?

Thanks in advance.